# Send email from code in PHP at localhost

Tags: javascript, php, email

I like to set up auto-send email from code at my local host.
I have code in PHP.

But not sure, what do I need to install or setup something at my localhost, so that my website can send email automatically.

My code is as follow.

```
    public function sendEmail_post()
    {
        $jdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $id = $jdata['id'];
        $query = $this->Register_model->sendEmail($id);
        $email = $query[0]->email;
        $token = $query[0]->token;
        $user_type = $this->Register_model->roleNames($id);
        if ($user_type != "Consumer") {
            $user_type = "admin";
        } else {
            $user_type = "user";
        }

        $this->email->from('no-reply@xxxxxxx.com', 'XXXXxxxx');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('Account Activation');
        $this->email->message('

Thanks for signing up!
Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below.


Please click this link to activate your account:
<a href="' . $this->config->item('emailRedirect') . $user_type . '/#/login?auth=' . sha1($email) . '&token=' . sha1($token) . '">Click here<a>'
        );

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        //$this->db->query('update user set token ="active",status="active" from user where email=$email');
        if ($this->email->send()) {

            $this->db->query("update user set emailverify='No' where email='$email'");
            //$this->Crud_model->verifyEmailID($e_mail);
            $this->response(array('result' => 'mail send successfully', 'success' => true), 200);
        } else {
            $this->response(array('result' => 'Failed to send Email', 'success' => false), 404);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you positively sure you are a JavaScript developer? This feels like PHP :-?

Comment: :) Sorry I am not web developer. I have updated. Thanks

Comment: If you want to send email you need an email server. But installing your own server is crazy. I suggest you just use the server you get with your `xxxxxxx.com` hosting service.

Comment: Whatever do you mean by automatically? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Use phpmailer, you will need an email server easiest way is to use a web host like gmail or whatever, just google for their smtp host.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

 $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply email code

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I hope this will helps you

```
    public function sendEmail_post()
    {
        $jdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $id = $jdata['id'];
        $query = $this->Register_model->sendEmail($id);
        $email = $query[0]->email;
        $token = $query[0]->token;
        $user_type = $this->Register_model->roleNames($id);
        if ($user_type != "Consumer") {
            $user_type = "admin";
        } else {
            $user_type = "user";
        }
        $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config)
        $this->email->from('no-reply@xxxxxxx.com', 'XXXXxxxx');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('Account Activation');
        $this->email->message('

Thanks for signing up!
Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below.


Please click this link to activate your account:
<a href="' . $this->config->item('emailRedirect') . $user_type . '/#/login?auth=' . sha1($email) . '&token=' . sha1($token) . '">Click here<a>'
        );

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        //$this->db->query('update user set token ="active",status="active" from user where email=$email');
        if ($this->email->send()) {

            $this->db->query("update user set emailverify='No' where email='$email'");
            //$this->Crud_model->verifyEmailID($e_mail);
            $this->response(array('result' => 'mail send successfully', 'success' => true), 200);
        } else {
            $this->response(array('result' => 'Failed to send Email', 'success' => false), 404);
        }
```